# Getting empty response from scraper when using crochet and flask?

Tags: flask, scrapy

I'm trying to understand make it work a `scrapy` scraper using `crochet` and `flask`. The scraper works, but I can't get the output.

The code is this:

```
import crochet
crochet.setup()

from time import sleep
from scrapy import signals
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,redirect,session, escape


from project.spiders.project_flask import FlaskScraperSpider

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'scrape_with_style!'

crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def scrape():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = request.json
        result = scrape_in_reactor(json_data)
        print(result)
        stashed = result.stash()
        session['download'] = stashed
        return "Starting download, refresh to track progress."
    
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        download = session.get('download', None)
        if download is None:
            return "No download in progress."
        try:
            result = crochet.retrieve_result(download)
            print(output_data)
            output_data1 = result.wait(timeout=0.1)
            return jsonify(output_data1)
        except crochet.TimeoutError:
            stashed = result.stash()
            print('STASHED ::> ',stashed)
            session['download'] = stashed
            return "Download in progress..."
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return "Download failed:\n" + str(e)
    
@crochet.run_in_reactor
def scrape_in_reactor(req):
    output_data = []
    dispatcher.connect(lambda item, response, spider: output_data.append(dict(item)), signal=signals.item_scraped)
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(FlaskScraperSpider, **req)
    eventual.addCallback(lambda _: output_data)
    return eventual

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=8080)
```

when I perform a GET request (after performing the POST request), I get `"Download in progress..."` and its okay because the scraper is actually scraping. But when the scraper is done, I get an empty list.

This is the last function of the spider:

```
def parse_data(self,response):
        data = response.json()
        opts = data.get('meta')
        if opts:
            time = data.get('time')
            for opt in opts:
                desc = opt.get('description')
                output_data = {
                    'time':time,
                    'desc':desc
                }
                yield output_data
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

My main goal is to run this scraper in a cloud service (like Cloud Run) and be able to parallelize requests from client.

EDIT: The code I made was based on the [docs](https://crochet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#run-in-reactor-asynchronous-results) and [this site](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/integrating-scrapy-with-flask-8611debc4579)

Comment: The first issue I see is that you never actually run the crawler with the twisted reactor.  The second issue I see is that you are bypassing the scrapy signalmanager and connecting directly to pydispatcher which is unlikely to yield the results you are looking for, and finally you never signal the reactor to stop which I suppose isn't actually an error since you never tell it to start either.